# how to convert objects into nodes

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath, marklogic, marklogic-8

I'd like to work with some document properties (which are in xml) as nodes so I can work with child elements. So far I have:

```
var counts = [];
for (var p of xdmp.documentProperties(uris)) {
    var isANode = p instanceof Node; // false (actually true - see edit)

    var count = xdmp.xqueryEval('fn:count(' + p + '//data)')
    counts.push(count)
}
counts
```

I've seen [nodebuilder](https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/sjs/working-with-xml) examples in the MarkLogic documentation and I'd like to use that interface. e.g.

```
myNode.xpath('//data')
var children = myNode.childNodes()
```

Instead of evaluating using XPath is there a way to I convert the object into a node? Alternatively, is there a better way to work with existing XML in Server Side JavaScript?

In XQuery I can use `xdmp:tranform-to-json()` but that function is not provided in SJS.

**EDIT:**

In my attempt to provide the a clean code sample I left out vital information. I had my code structured as follows:

```
for (var uri of cts.uriMatch('/pattern/*')) {
    var p = xdmp.documentProperties(uri);
    var isANode = p instanceof Node; // false
    // ...
}
```

instead of

```
for (var p of xdmp.documentProperties(cts.uriMatch('/pattern/*'))) {
    var isANode = p instanceof Node; // true
    // ...
}
```

The type returned is a `ValueIterator` which equivalent of an XQuery sequence and can be accessed using:

```
xdmp.documentProperties(uri).next().value
```

Comment: Opinion-based: I always parse my xml to json before doing any logic. Made life alot easier if you don't like working with xml.

Comment: @Shilly: Do you mean on the database or when you iterate over an XML element? How are you converting your XML in javascript to JSON?

Comment: When I receive the data from the server, before using it. For complex xml documents I just loop over all the child nodes and save the values in nested objects. For simple xml, I just parse out the relevant data with a regex. (not adviced for non-simple xml) Or have a look at the plugins for your framework. Almost all of them have some xml and json utils these days.

Comment: @Shilly: That's exactly what I'd like to figure out: how to loop over all child nodes. In my example they are not nodes but when I print them they are xml. i.e. x instanceof Node === false. I want to convert my Values into Nodes so I can access the child elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked for me in QConsole:

```js
var uris = ['/test.xml', '/test2.xml'];
var counts = [];
for (var p of xdmp.documentProperties(uris)) {
    counts.push(fn.count(p.xpath('//data')))
}
counts
```

In my test each p was a Node. I created some sample data with an xquery script.

```xq
let $test-data := (
  <priority>
    <data>hello</data>
  </priority>,
  <status>
    <data>hi</data>
  </status>
)
return
(
  xdmp:document-set-properties("/test.xml", $test-data),
  xdmp:document-set-properties("/test2.xml", $test-data)
)
```